# Start the ReactJS App without port

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native, bundle, react-router

I am working on ReactJS application using create-react-app.

The npm start and npm run build application is working fine, The application is running in a port number like 4000 or pushstate-server build in the port 9000, The problem is that I need to run the build application without port number in a public url like http://sample/home/ , when I browse directly the build/index.html it is showing the home page correctly but the routings is not working as like in port,All of the css and assets are showing not found.

Answer (score 2):

Change the port to 80.

This is the default value for HTTP requests, so, when you try to access
`www.google.com`
in fact you are accessing
`www.google.com:80`

Comment: I set the port to 80,but the result is same as above, the home is working fine,the remaining pages are showing 404 Not found

Comment: You need an http server that handles the requests to your routes, you can't simply open the `index.html`. That's what `pushstate-server` does. If you can't use it in production, move to hash based history.

Comment: @VenkateshSomu that's probably a clue that you have another problem that is unrelated to what port is being used. Your browser will have developer tools with with a javascript console, see if it is outputting any errors.

Comment: @Gimby , While using pushstate server or http server it is running fine but I need to run without the server like this,need to host the completed app in public url.

Answer (score 0):

You have to serve your app with a webserver instead of Webpack Dev Server, which is a dev tool which is not made for production.

Checkout my answer here for more information: [How can I serve a reactjs app through https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134577/how-can-i-serve-a-reactjs-app-through-https/53134717?noredirect=1#comment93163047_53134717)