# How can I serve a reactjs app through https?

Tags: reactjs, https, server, react-router

it is my first post here.

Well, I made a lot of research before posting here and I really couldn't understand how to serve a reactjs app created with create-react-app (and compilted/built with it) through the https protocol.

I have got the self signed certificate but the "serve" npm package that I use (and which is the one the built create-react-app app is meant to be served with) can apparently not serve through https.

I also tried changing the server package, I tried [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) which seemed perfect for me except I use React Router in my app and this server can't deal with that.

I heard about using apache/nginx as a reverse proxy, could someone explain me how this works?

Have a nice day, Gab

Answer (score -1):

You have to build your React app `npm run build`, then, take the dist folder, and serve it using your favorite webserver, like Apache or Nginx.

This medium post should be a good starting point : https://medium.com/@jgefroh/a-guide-to-using-nginx-for-static-websites-d96a9d034940

**Never ever serve a production app with Webpack Dev Server**, it's a dev tool and it's not made for production.

Comment: Alright thank you really much for you advise and information!